# Prove that the following polynomial has at least two real roots

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, roots

> Let $P(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x+\dots+a_{2n}x^{2n}$. Given $a_{2n}>0$ and there exists an $x_0$ with $P(x_0)<0$, prove that this polynomial function has at least two distinct roots over $\Bbb R$.

My idea is to find an $x>x_0$ where $y>0$ and an $x<x_0$ where $y>0$ but I am not sure how to do that, I'll be thankful if someone could point me to the direction.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is actually quite easy.

Comment: What flavour root would you like? Real?

Comment: @AdamHrankowski yes

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I don't have a given root, my question is a little bit different

Comment: You won't get any specific value.  But note as $x$ becomes very large positive or large negative the $a_{2n}x^{2n}$ term becomes most dominant.

Comment: What is lim P(x) as x goes to infinity, lim P(x) as x goes to neg infinity?

Comment: @fleablood if i am not mistaken both of the limits are infinity becuase x have an even power ?

Comment: So it has to be positive eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the leading coefficient of $P(x)$ is positive, as $x\to\pm\infty$ the $x^{2n}$ term dominates and $P(x)\to+\infty$. Therefore, there are two points $a$ and $b$ with $a<x_0<b$ where $P(a)>0$ and $P(b)>0$. By the intermediate value theorem, there must be at least one root in each of the disjoint intervals $(a,x_0)$ and $(x_0,b)$, making for at least two distinct roots.